# Total Commander for Android : multi rename tool

Tags: file-management, files

I am sure I am missing something here and a quick fast dirty attempt yielded nothing.

I would like to rename all files in a specific directory using total commander for Android multi rename tool so that all extensions have JPG and only the first five letters of the filename are included in the rename.

```
asssdd.0
sloppyjoeontop.0
gghhhh.0
```

results

```
asss.jpg
sloppy.jpg
gghhh.jpg
```

How can this be done?

I tried to replace everything aka `*` with  name placeholder aka `[N1-5]` and then the extension. This respects the extension and changes it but there is no change in the name.See screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Source**](https://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=42775)

After breaking my head for an hour figured it out and it turns out to be quite simple!(see source)

From my call recorder files in `mp3` format, I picked up two records and changed the file name to conceal identity/number in the file name . I wanted to convert them to `jpg` files with only the first five letters in file name.

That is

`nonsense name 914850098765678902345.mp3` → `nonse.jpg`

`abracadabra 2021-09-24 14.19.44_O_P330.mp3` → `abrac.jpg`

All you need to do is to enter `[N1-5]` in the name mask, which means retain first five characters in the file name and enter the desired extension. Nothing else.

Click <kbd>START!</kbd> and you are done!

[image]

Here are the changes in the folder for these two files

[image]

You can also undo the changes by selecting the changed files, going to Multi-rename tool and `...` → undo last operation. If you need to do these operations frequently, from the 3 dots options save as a profile and use that profile to save yourself the bother of setting it up again.